# jquery clone last table row with excludes

Tags: jquery, find, clone

I have an input table which it's last row is:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
           <input type="hidden" value="" readonly="" size="3" name="id[]">
       </td>
<td>
      <input type="hidden" value="" readonly="" size="3" name="fkcommand[]">
      </td>
<td>
<select name="type[]">
<option value="C" selected="selected">C</option>
<option value="P">P</option></select>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="input" value="1200" size="6" name="strike[]">
</td><td>
      <input type="input" value="-2" size="6" name="quantity[]">
    </td>
    </tr>
```

and I want to clone this input line, empty it's values **except for the hidden value fkcommand** and append it the end of the table

I am using this:

```
var row = $(this).parent().find('table tbody tr:last');
row.clone().find('input').val('').end().insertAfter(row).find('[name=fkcommand[]]').val('222');
```

which doesn't add the value '222' to fkcommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the problem is in the selector. It is better to quote the attribute values:

```
.find("[name='fkcommand[]']")
```

However, I suggest you to rewrite your code in such manner:

```
row.clone().insertAfter(row).find("input").each(function() {
    this.value = this.name == "fkcommand[]" ? "222" : "";
});
```

Comment: thanks, your selector `.find("[name='fkcommand[]']")` did the trick.. :-)

Comment: I would avoid using such selectors wherever possible.  It is absolutely horrible regarding performance.  Use the id/node name selector whenever you can.  jQuery was built for chaining, and it has been demonstrated that using massive selector strings is ridiculously slow.  The fastest way to find an element is purely the use of the id selector.  Adding more to the id selector (class name/position/etc) actually slows the search.  You should also preload DOM references wherever possible:

Comment: var reference = $('#whatever');

Comment: @AndrewRhyne Although what you say is correct, cloning elements with IDs will give problems in the markup (IDs should be unique). On the other hand, `querySelector`, which is primarily used by jQuery, can do by-attribute selection as fast as by-class selection.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go

```
var clonedRow = $(table).last('tr').clone();
```

Comment: doesn't solve the empting problem, empty everything then the fkcommand field.

Comment: if you put id's on these elements it will not only be easier to do, but your application will perform better.  The post below should help